# Updating theme on sunset in a React Native app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-native

We have an app with day and night modes. Going between modes is a simple boolean switch. What we'd like to do is have the modes auto-toggle at sunset from day to night.

Currently, this switch occurs in our root container's `componentWillReceiveProps`. I don't love this approach as it only fires when renders occur. My thought was to set up a simple looping `interval` to check for the current time every few minutes or so, but we already have a couple intervals running throughout and in a React Native app, I'm not sure how performant multiple, ongoing polls like that would be.

Is it fine to use an interval here or might there be a better method for time tracking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the performance impact of setting a timer. I'm not sure about RN but in browsers usually Javascript timing gets its own thread anyway.

What you do need to worry about is not setting the intervals too short (since whatever the timer will call is itself synchronous), nor too long (> 1min) as on Android long timers [keep the Timing module awake](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981). Most importantly you need to make sure the timer is cleaned up on unmount - see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-native-background-timer](https://github.com/ocetnik/react-native-background-timer) to emit events periodically even when the app is in background.

```
const getCurrentMode = () => {
    let mode
    const afternoon = 12
    const evening = 17
    const currentHour = moment().format("HH")

    if(currentHour >= afternoon && currentHour <= evening) {
        mode = "afternoon";
    } else if(currentHour >= evening) {
        mode = "evening";
    } else {
        mode = "morning";
    }
    return mode
}

import BackgroundTimer from 'react-native-background-timer';
import moment from 'moment'

componentDidMount() {
  BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
    const currentMode = getCurrentMode()
    if(currentMode !== this.state.currentMode) {
       this.setState({currentMode})
    }
  }, 200); // ... Set the delay here in ms
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```